# list of checkbox not allow to me checked any item if item not equal ALL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am working on an asp.net razor page. I face issue where I can't select any checkbox checked except all.

If all checkbox checked then all checked check box it working correctly.

If all checkbox not checked then all checkbox not checked and it working correctly.

My issue when select any item not equal All then it will not checked if I select.

So how to solve this issue?

**Code Snippet**

```js
$(document).on('change', '.classCheckbox', function(event) {

  var allCheckbox = $('.classCheckbox[value="0"]');
  var checkboxes = $('.classCheckbox').not(allCheckbox);

  if (allCheckbox.prop('checked')) {
    checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
  }
  var selectedClassIds = [];
  var selectedClassIdsValues = []; // Array to store selected values

  $('.classCheckbox:checked').each(function() {
    selectedClassIds.push($(this).val());
    selectedClassIdsValues.push($(this).next('span').text());
  });

  if (selectedClassIds.length > 0) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '?handler=CheckedAccountClassName',
      type: 'GET',
      traditional: true,
      data: {
        classIds: selectedClassIds,
        classIdsValues: selectedClassIdsValues
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $('#subClassesList').empty();
        $('#subClassesContainer').show();

        var subClassesContainer = $('<div data-class-id="' + selectedClassIds + '"></div>');
        $.each(response, function(i, item) {
          $(subClassesContainer).append('<input type="checkbox" class="subclassCheckbox" name="selectedSubClasses" value="' + item.subClassAccountId + '" /> ' + item.subClassAccountName + '<br />');
        });
        $('#subClassesList').append(subClassesContainer);
      }
    });
  }
})
```

```css
label {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" class="classCheckbox" value="0">All</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="classCheckbox" value="X">X</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="classCheckbox" value="Y">Y</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="classCheckbox" value="Z">Z</label>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: so please how to solve this issue can you please post modifications that can make my code working perfectly

Comment: like your last question, this has nothing to do with asp.net core or razor pages or any server-side technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the checkbox which checked currently has value `0` depending on this select all checkbox or remove checked.

***Demo Code :***

```js
$(document).on('change', '.classCheckbox', function(event) {
  var allCheckbox = $('.classCheckbox[value="0"]');
  var checkboxes = $('.classCheckbox').not(allCheckbox);

  //check if checkbox has value = 0
  if ($(this).val() == "0") {
    checkboxes.prop('checked', allCheckbox.prop('checked')) //true or false
  }

  var selectedClassIds = [];
  var selectedClassIdsValues = []; // Array to store selected values

  $('.classCheckbox:checked').each(function() {
    selectedClassIds.push($(this).val());
    selectedClassIdsValues.push($(this).next('span').text()); // ??
  });
  console.log('selected:', ...selectedClassIds);
  if (selectedClassIds.length > 0) {
    //your ajax call
  }
})
```

```css
label {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" class="classCheckbox" value="0">All</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="classCheckbox" value="X">X</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="classCheckbox" value="Y">Y</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="classCheckbox" value="Z">Z</label>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this... ?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#cAll, #cX, #cY, #cZ')
.forEach( (cbx,_,All) =>
  {
  cbx.addEventListener('change', ()=>
    {
    if (cbx.checked && cbx.value === '0')
      All.forEach( c => c.checked = true);
    else if (!cbx.checked)
      All[0].checked = false;
    })
  });
```

```css
label { 
  display : block;
  margin  : .4em;
  border  : 1px lightblue solid;
  width   : 6em;
  padding : .2em .5em;
  cursor  : pointer;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="cAll" value="0"> All </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="cX"   value="X"> X   </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="cY"   value="Y"> Y   </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="cZ"   value="Z"> Z   </label>
```